# PHP & jQuery form submission issue

Tags: php, jquery, sql, forms

I'm creating website project where you can edit a post after it has been published. I've a made the site with PHP, SQL and jQuery, and all posts that are published to the site gets outputted to the websites "feed" via a while-loop (not included in this questions content). All posts have a unique ID added to them when they are published (in the database).

The issue I now have is that the second form (*post__edit*) doesn't prompt at all.

I've figured out that I need to pass the id of a post inside an `<input type="hidden" value="$postID">` field. This form below just prompts the actual *post_edit* form that is used to submit a post change.

```
echo '
 <form method="post"> 
   <button type="button" class="post__editBtn">Edit post</button> 
   <input type="hidden" name="post__editHidden" value="'.$postID.'">
 </form>';
```

When the button class: `post__editBtn` gets clicked a jQuery click eventlistener is triggered that fades in the form (*post_edit*) that let's you make the changes to a post and submit them.

```
$('.post__editBtn').click(function() {
    $('.post__edit').fadeIn();
});
```

Then what I have is a PHP if-statement that checks if the hidden value has been set. If it has then I echo out the previously hidden form, and assigns a SESSION variable to be used later on when doing the UPDATE query.

```
if(isset($_POST['post__editHidden'])) {
  $_SESSION['post__editHidden'] = $_POST['post__editHidden'];

  echo'
  <form method="post" action="../../php/includes/updatePost.php" class="post__edit">
   <input type="text" name="postTitle" placeholder="Edit title" required>
   <textarea name="postMsg" maxlength="255" placeholder="Edit message" required></textarea>
   <button type="submit">Edit Post</button>
   <button class="post__edit-close">Close</button>
  </form>';
 }
```

To sumarize

- The first form triggers the jQuery fadeIn effect for the correct post (with *$postID*)
- The jQuery just fades in the second form (*post__edit*)
- The second form (*post__edit*) takes the `post__editHidden` value (the correct ID for the correct post) and assigns it to a SESSION variable that can later be used to make the SQL UPDATE query, that runs when the second form is finally submitted (to updatePost.php).

I believe that because I have the first forms button set to `type="button"` it doesn't submit the form so `isset($_POST['post__editHidden']` doesn't run. But if I change the button to a normal submit type then the first form is just summited and reloads the page which it's on. I could maybe just `e.preventDefault` in my jQuery fadeIn, but I don't know if that works.

I'm quite new to PHP and SQL so I might have it all wrong. Thanks anyways!

Comment: There's no submit button in the form with the hidden input.

Comment: All the php and initial HTML forms are in the same page? php_self ?

Comment: @Bilel both HTML forms are on the same page (in the same php script), they are outputted in a while loop that checks a DB table for posts that then shows all posts.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I stated that in the post. If I have a button with the type submit then the page just reloads and the secondary form isn't shown. But I don't know how to better structure the script.

Comment: There are different ways to solve it... like by adding Ids to forms and handle that using On submit method...

Comment: you can add to a specific submit buttons to each forms both forms and buttons have different IDs then you treat them separately using jQuery. and use e.preventDefault for the first form

Comment: And your input hidden should be reused in the second form... the one being sent to php ;)

Comment: And to be honest to bring you a better simplified solution! It's better you explain us the whole idea :) Like the initial loop is displaying multiple forms... ? And why the session variable (id) is being used at all?

Comment: Assuming you have multiple buttons and multiple forms, your code is too ambiguous to be effective. Also you do not need a Form to create a button. You can simply have a button that is scripted to reveal a specific form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's more of a suggested alternative than an answer.**

---

The session variable usage would be more useful in other cases where we could obfuscate the ID value for example or reuse it in an orphan (disconnected) navigation level...

But in this case, I'd better use an only one form and fill it's input values using Ajax.

This Demo updates values only for postId' 32... It should work when it's used alongside a functional dynamic ajax handler that gets an Id and returns it's jSon object.

```js
$('.post__editBtn').click(function() {
var myform = $('.post__edit');
var postId=$(this).attr('data-id');
    myform.find("input[name='post__editHidden']" ).val(postId);    
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/kx5xs", // replace with php later
        data: {id: postId},
        success: function(data) {
           myform.find("input[name='postTitle']" ).val(data[0].title);
          myform.find("textarea[name='postMsg']" ).val(data[0].content);
        },
        error : function(){
           alert('Some error...!');
        }
    });
    
    $('.post__edit').fadeIn();
    
    
    //for demo puropose to show the new value in the update form:
    console.log($(".post__edit input[name='post__editHidden']").val());
});
```

```css
.post__edit{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"post">
   Post 30<button type="button" data-id="30" class="post__editBtn">Edit post</button> 
   </div>
<div class"post">   
   Post 32<button type="button" data-id="32" class="post__editBtn">Edit post</button> 
</div>   
<div class"post">
     Post 37 <button type="button" data-id="37" class="post__editBtn">Edit post</button> 
</div>      
   <!--all data-id values would be replaced with '.$postID.' in the php loop-->
 
 <form method="post" action="../../php/includes/updatePost.php" class="post__edit">
   <input type="text" name="postTitle" placeholder="Edit title" required>
   <textarea name="postMsg" maxlength="255" placeholder="Edit message" required></textarea>
   <button type="submit">Save Post</button>
   <button class="post__edit-close">Close</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="post__editHidden" value="">
  </form>
```

And we add a file ex:ajax.php that we call with ajax where we get an ID, we do get that record from the database to return our json. Something like this :

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['id'];
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT title,content * FROM posts WHERE postId=$id LIMIT 1");
$result=...
echo json_encode($result);
```

To get a jSon like this :

```
{"id": "32","title": "POst 32","content": "POst 32 talks about HiTECH"}
```

Comment: Thx got it working with just changing the first form buttons to include data-id=$postID and then via jQuery find the data-id and add its value to the empty input type="hidden" field. Thx again!

Comment: Glad it helped! What I suggested is a different form processing approach. Good luck :)